# Calculating transfer function of a linear time varying system?

Tags: continuous-signals, linear-systems, transfer-function, laplace-transform

If we excite a LTI system with the Dirac delta $\delta(t)$, the system outputs the impulse response $h(t)$. For a LTI system, it doesn't matter when we excite the system with the Dirac delta, we will always get the same impulse response.

However, that is not the case for a linear time-varying (LTV) system. If, say, we excite a system at $t_{0}$ then its impulse response will be different than if we excite the same system at $t_{1}$ so the impulse response $h(t,t_{0})$ is a function of $t_{0}$. However, since the $t$ part is completely separable from the $t_{0}$ part, we can express the impulse response of a system as the multiplication of $2$ signals $g(t_{0})$, which shows the dependence of the impulse response on the moment of excitation and $h(t)$ which is the impulse response if the system was linear and time invariant so $h(t, t_{0}) = g(t_{0})h(t)$

Suppose now we have a system for which it is true that if $t_{2} = t_{1} + t_{0}$ then $$ h(t,t_{2}) = h(t,t_{1}) + h(t,t_{0}) $$ By substitution, we get $$ g(t_{2})h(t) = g(t_{1}) h(t) + g(t_{0}) h(t) \to g(t_{2}) = g(t_{1}) + g(t_{0}) $$ which is interesting because it means that $g(t)$ is a linear signal. Because it is a linear signal, we can choose to express in any form of a linear signal but lets say for simplicity $g(t) = At$.Because we have the values for $g(t_{1}),g(t_{0}),t_{1},t_{0}$ we can determine $A$.

---

**Example:** Suppose we have the linear time varying system with a impulse response of $h(t,t_{0}) = \frac{t_{0}}{t}$. We can write $h(t,t_{0}) = g(t_{0})h(t)$ where $h(t) = \frac{1}{t}$ and $g(t_{0}) = t_{0}$. We can easily prove that this system satisfies the condition of the article.So now let's find $g(t)$. Well $A = \frac{g(t_{1})-g(t_{0})}{t_{1}-t_{0}} = 1$ so $g(t) = t$.Now $g(t)\cdot h(t) = t\cdot t^{-1} = 1$.

Since the system is linear we can safely head to the Laplace domain in which $H(s)$ or the transfer function will be $\frac{1}{s}$. So now have I calculated the transfer function of a time varying system? Is my process correct?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146345/discussion-on-question-by-volpina-calculating-transfer-function-of-a-linear-time); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Peter, I am not wanting to disregard your instruction, but I wanna see the math rendered. - - - - @Jazzmaniac , maybe the simplest way to put it is that, if the LTV system varies sufficiently slowly, the frequency response of the system during some time close to $t_0$ would be:  $$ H(f, t_0) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(t, t_0) \, e^{-j 2 \pi f t} \ \mathrm{d}t \ \cdot \ e^{j 2 \pi f t_0}$$

The $e^{j 2 \pi f t_0}$ factor at the end it compensate for the delay $t_0$ exactly as we would if $h(t, t_0) = h(t-t_0)$ and it became LTI.  Just for consistency.

Comment: I guess, by extension, that means that, if the LTV system varies sufficiently slowly, the Laplace-like transfer function would be:

$$ H(s, t_0) = \mathscr{L}\Big\{ h(t, t0) \Big\} \ \cdot \ e^{s \, t_0} = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(t, t_0) \, e^{-st} \, \mathrm{d}t \ \cdot \ e^{s \, t_0}$$

That way if the system degenerates to an LTI system (because it varies extremely slowly), then the transfer function $H(s, t_0)$ is not a function of $t_0$.

Comment: We need to be clear that, in LTV system theory, $h(t, t_0)$ means the impulse response of the system, measured at time $t$, of a unit impulse that was applied at time $t_0$.  If the LTV system degenerates to one that doesn't vary much and then is considered LTI, then $$h(t, t_0) = h(t - t_0) \ .$$  So, I think that if $h(t,t_0)$ is separable, then we need to say that $$ h(t, t_0) = g(t_0) \, h(t-t_0) $$

Comment: In the example I give t is completely seperable from $t_{0}$.Does this mean the derivation is correct?

Answer (score 3):

> However, since the $t$ part is completely separable from the $t_0$

Where does that come from? In most cases the time variance is not separable from the a "time-invariant" impulse response.

A simple (and very common) example of a time variant impulse response is a variable delay, i.e.

$$h(t,t_0) = \delta(t-\Delta(t_0))$$

where $\Delta(t_0)$ is the delay as a function of time.

Physically this happen when either source and receiver are moving or if the propagation medium changes temperature/pressure/impedance, etc.

For example if you have microphone on a stand and the stand wiggles a bit, you get something like

$$h(t,t_0) = \delta \left[ t-\frac{R+r_v\cos(\omega_v\cdot t_0)}{c_0} \right]$$

where $R$ is the bulk distance between the microphone and the loudspeaker, $c_0$ the speed of sound, $r_v$ the amplitude of the microphone movement and $\omega_v$ the frequency of the microphone movement.

You can certainly construct examples where the time invariance is separable, but it's not the general case.

Comment: Does $\Delta(t_0)$ mean that it's an arbitrary real and non-negative function of $t_0$?

Comment: Yes. I can add a few examples.

Comment: Hil, remember that when $t=t_0$, that's the beginning of the impulse.  So, if the impulse is delayed by $t_0$, so also is the impulse response.  If it's LTV, then it is delayed and changed.  So a wire (which is also LTI) would have $h(t,t_0)=\delta(t-t_0)$.   I think your microphone on a wiggling stand might be:

$$h(t,t_0) = \delta \left( t-t_0 - \frac{R+r_v\cos(\omega_v\cdot t_0)}{c_0} \right)$$

and I think that $R$ should be the bulk distance between the vocalist's lips and the loudspeaker when the microphone is in the middle of its wiggle.

Comment: @Hilmar well in the example I give I can seperate t from $t_{0}$.Does this means what I have calculated is correct?

Answer (score 0):

> However, since the t
> part is completely separable from the t0
> part

To add to @Hilmar's [answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/88032/63763), and give you a way to devise your own counter-examples, as you requested in the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146345/discussion-on-question-by-volpina-calculating-transfer-function-of-a-linear-time), if that were true then for values $t_0, t_1, t_2, t_3$, and assuming $h()$ is defined for all 4 combinations, you'd have:
$$h(t_0,t_1)h(t_2,t_3) = g(t_1)h(t_0)g(t_3)h(t_2) = h(t_2,t_1)h(t_0,t_3)$$
Now consider (*out of thousand others*) $h(t,t_0) = t+t_0$. Then
$$h(2,2)h(3,4) = 4\cdot 7 = 28 \neq 30 = 5 \cdot 6 = h(3,2)h(2,4)$$

Comment: in the example I give t is completely seperable from $t_{0}$.Does this mean my derivation is correct?

Comment: @volpina Do you want to know if it’s correct for the *specific* example you gave?

Comment: yes I would like to know.