# Equipment to test my theory on time varying systems

Tags: convolution, linear-systems, impulse-response, laplace-transform

How can I make a [linearly time varying](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/88023/calculating-transfer-function-of-a-linear-time-varying-system) system to test my theory?

Can I ask for a PID microcontroller available from my university such that $K$ is gradually increased from 0 to $c$

Comment: So, the nice thing about deterministic signal processing is that it's relatively easy to simulate 100% correctly: when you say you want to model a *linearly time varying system*, that just means you said "I have this set of equations, and I want a system to implement them". And computers are good at that. So, your university would reasonably ask you whether something is broken about your laptop/PC, as that's where you'd implement that. Can you elaborate on what exactly you want to build, what theory to test? To me, this seems like a *significantly* underdefined task, and I'd be careful about

Comment: spending any funding on it without a much more detailed description of *why* you need to buy – even a 10€ device costs a high multiple of that, because acquisitions go through bureaucratic steps more complex than the math you would be doing on your laptop. So, **please expand your question with what you want to model and test**, otherwise this is unspecific, too broad and potentially but based on opinions.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm not asking them to buy anything, I just want them to check it out using currently available equipment. Also I'm quite unsure on how to implement such a system in Matlab because you would need to take into account the debugging time interval which I simply don't know how to do it.

Comment: @EdV That's a very cool topic for research!

Comment: But that's the thing:  you're writing your question from a computer, and you're asking about another computer (a microcontroller) to test your theory – just don't do it on the other computer, do it on yours. Your theory, if it applies to time-varying linear systems, can be tested in Matlab, python, C++, or any other software approach you like. You adding external hardware doesn't help you at all! Also, before any engineer starts putting any kind of system on a microcontroller, they model it, on their PC. So, you're not even saving any effort there – if you think debugging things in Matlab (or

Comment: any other software on your PC) is hard: True, but debugging real-world systems is much harder! So. Yeah. You'll need to model your system in software first, because as it stands now, you don't even have a rudimentary description of what hardware you'd need, so we couldn't even help you with choosing from the available hardware. Again, the available hardware I'd recommend is: A PC running Python, Matlab, or any language you're familiar with.

Comment: **Or, maybe ask you this the other way around**: What functionality would a microcontroller board give you that your PC does not, which is relevant to testing your hypothesis right now? It's really not clear to me!

Comment: @MarcusMüller if I knew how to implement a signal in real time in MATLAB ,I wouldnt be asking it.You can post a answer explaining how I can do it in MATLAB.

Comment: Do *what*? That is what I'm asking you to actually describe. This is the first time you mention you need your signal to be in real time. And the immediate follow up question there is why you would need that to test a theory. You wouldn't need it at all to simulate a bunch of equations. I really do like Ed V's enthusiasm here, but I don't see how giving you hardware to play with helps verify a theory if you cannot simulate the same in software first. What do you think is possible to do on a microcontroller, which also just runs software that you couldn't do in software running on your computer?

Comment: Please put in words why you need a physical device to test your hypothesis, from beginning to conclusive end, without taking shortcuts like saying "I don't know how", because this might let us know how was can help you best.